# Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 912

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I started getting this error after the last update.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line:
>   912
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
>
> > A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> > Could not create task ':app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug'.
> > > No signature of method: org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.destinationDir() is applicable for
> > argument types: (File) values:
> > [C:\Users\gurka\OneDrive\Belgeler\GitHub\projectname\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug]
>
> - Try:
>
> > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> > Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BU�LD FAILED in 2s

**I tried flutter clean e.g**

**flutter run -v result**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue.

This solved it for me:

- Downgraded to a previous android gradle plugin version (in `build.gradle`) 7.2.2 works for me
- Deleted .gradle folder
- Restarted Android Studio with `Invalidate caches..`

Could be that any one of these measures would have been enough.